# getting value of exec sql statement within stored procedure

Tags: sql, exec, return-value

I am running several select statements and need to check the values of each select statement, and in some cases compare them to values of other select statements all from within the same stored procedure and then return a value back to my program.  Here is some of my code:

```
DECLARE @statement AS VARCHAR(MAX)
Declare @result as integer

set @statement = 'SELECT Count (*) FROM tooling.dbo.PTA00015 Where PTA00015.TD0001 = ''' +   @ToolCode + '''' 
Exec (@statement)
```

I need the value from this to know if the return value is 0 or not.  IF <> 0 I have another select statement that when it returns a value I need to compare that to this original select statement.  Depending on if they match I need to return a value back to my program basically MATCH or NOT MATCH.

How do I get the value from the EXEC and use that for comparison?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you simply use

```
set @count = SELECT Count (*) FROM tooling.dbo.PTA00015 Where PTA00015.TD0001 =  @ToolCode
```

And use @count directly to compare with the other value?